# Python3 failing to convert str to dict or json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

```
r = requests.get(http_get_url, headers=headers)
r = r.text
r = r.replace("true", "True")
z = json.loads(r)
```

however, instead of loading the json (or python dict), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noir/PycharmProjects/Work_Projects/get_errors.py", line 21, in <module>
    get_errors(id)
  File "/home/noir/PycharmProjects/Work_Projects/get_errors.py", line 17, in get_errors
    z = json.loads(r)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 26 (char 28)
```

The result of `print(type(r))` is `<class 'str'>`

and the output of `print(r)` after converting 'true' to 'True' is:

```
{
    "HasItemsWithCount": True,
    "Collection": [

            {
            "GroupId" : "14",
            "Time" : "5/16/18, 5:02 PM",
            "File" : "[ESCAPE[]]",
            "Message" : "[ESCAPE[Client was restarted during backup, session may be incomplete.]]",
            "Count" : "3"
            },

    ]
}
```

So I fail to understand why the correctly formatted string of *r* fails to import into json.

Also, if I take this output and write it directly into python via copy/paste, the type of the variable is dict, showing me that the text is formatted correctly for a dict in Python. So I'm not sure why json.loads fails.

Comment: Remove this line `r = r.replace("true", "True")`.

Comment: The first question is: why is this URL returning something that's sort of like JSON, but isn't JSON? Is this not-quite-JSON format actually documented by whoever maintains that page? Or, if it's supposed to be JSON but fails, is that caused by code that you wrote, and can fix, or that a coworker wrote, and can fix if you threaten to kick him, or that a company you're working with wrote, and can fix it if you threaten to stop paying them? Because fixing code to generate proper JSON is a lot easier, and more robust, than writing code to parse broken almost-JSON.

Comment: Given that there are two problems in just this tiny example (`True` for `true`, and trailing commas), I wouldn't be surprised if there are other problems in other examples that you haven't looked at yet. Especially if there are any messages with Unicode text in them, or newlines, or quotes, or any null values.

Comment: what does the original response look like, the r.text value ?

Comment: Same as above, but with a lowercase t in true.

Answer (score 1):

Your replace is backwards:

Instead of:

```
r = r.replace("true", "True")
```

Try:

```
r = r.replace("True", "true")
```

Comment: You also have an extra `,` in your example

Comment: Sorry, the True was originally true, but converted to True by the line you are referencing.